# using playbackagent for windows phone 8.1 in MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to play audio in background, I have made a project using MVVM light Desing pattern.
 After some research I found this [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319) that helped to implement playbackagent in windows phone 8.1! 
My goal is to implement the Agent in my solution with MVVM Pattern.
Could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I can provide some general rules:

- Put business logic / condictional code into the ViewModel.
- Your View (.xaml.cs) files should only have minimum and necessary code for UI
- Use the service locator to always have one instance of the music player (which can be warped inside a controller).
- Use Messenger service to send data / notify the player from difference view models

Comment: One do not put **business logic** into the ViewModel! ViewModels aren't your business domain, they are your Presentation layer. **ONLY** presentation logic goes into the ViewModel, **NEVER** business logic

Comment: @thang2410199 the answer is not much clear , can you explore more yout idea ?

Comment: @thang2410199 : i need help please !

Comment: @MedMANS what do you need more explanation? IMO the keywords provided is fairly good to start with.

Comment: @thang2410199 : i need to know where can i start the background audio task ? in my view model i can't call dispatcher ton run async the playing ! please refer to the sample above to know about what i need help ! thanks